# How are unqualified-ids other than identifier categorized in terms of lvalue and rvalue?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

It seems that the standard does not explicitly talk about the expression categories of some *unqualified-id*s. On the other hand, an *identifier*, which is one of *unqualified-id*s, is categorized as follows:

> The result is an lvalue if the entity is a function, variable, or data member and a prvalue otherwise.

Then, what about other *unqualified-id*s—*operator-function-id*, *conversion-function-id*, *literal-operator-id*, ~*class-name*, ~*decltype-specifier*, *template-id*?

Comment: I guess those expressions (except for template-ids) can never occur by themselves, e.g. `operator X;` does not seem to be a legal expression-statement. However, `operator X();` is accepted as expression-statement by clang++ and g++, and [expr.call]p1 requires the `operator X`-part to be an expression of "function type or pointer to function type". Not sure if value category is required for anything.

Comment: This is [CWG issue 536](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue536)

Comment: @dyp I have thought exactly the same as you—that they are not used independently. However, I still wonder if there is any restriction that prevents them from occuring alone.

Comment: There is [expr.prim.general]p13, but it doesn't apply to *literal-operator-id*s (as well as *template-id*s). In fact, *literal-operator-id*s seem to be allowed as expression-statements: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a696e9917882a29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been acknowledged as [Core Working Group issue 536](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue536) which has been submitted almost 10 years ago. So probably it hasn't been deemed important enough to be fixed.

> More importantly, some kinds of *id-expressions* are not described by
>   5.1.1 [expr.prim.general]. The structure of this section is that the result, type, and lvalue-ness are specified for each of the cases it
>   covers [...]
>
> This treatment leaves unspecified all the non-*identifier*
>   *unqualified-id*s (*operator-function-id*, *conversion-function-id*, and
>   *template-id*) [...]
>
> -- *CWG 536*

---

From the behaviour of various compilers, we can assume the intention is that all of those expressions follow the rule for identifiers:

> The type of the expression is the type of the *identifier*. The result is the entity denoted by the identifier. The result is an lvalue if the entity is a function, variable, or data member and a prvalue otherwise.
>
> -- *post-N4296 [expr.prim.general]p13*

By the way: all of those expressions but *template-id*s can only refer to functions. *Template-id*s can refer to variables as well. Both *template-id*s and ordinary *identifier*s can refer to classes and enums, which confused me slightly (can there be expressions such as `int`? are they prvalues?)